# Based on which checkboxes are checked, display string array values in textView

Tags: android

This might be a bit too much asked for but I need it as a core functionality in my app. I have gotten several categories in strings.xml organized in string-array's :

```
<string-array name="sport_array">
    <item>Juggle a soccer ball for at least 25 times!</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="ff_array">
    <item>Make your friend or family member some scrambled egg for breakfast!</item>
    <item>Play hide and seek with your friends!</item>
    <item>Go outside and pick some flowers for your best friend!</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="money_array">
    <item>Head over to the movie house!</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="outside_array">
    <item>Go outside and pick some flowers for your best friend!</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="school_array">
    <item>Help your neighbour with his homework!</item>
    <item>During your lunch break, go talk to one of your teachers! They might have something interesting to share with you</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="fitness_array">
    <item>Do 10 push-ups without stopping</item>
    <item>Do 15 dips without stopping</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="photo_array">
    <item>Take a selfie with a stranger!</item>
    <item>Give it your best, take the best picture in history!</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="beach_array">
    <item>Gather with your best friends and have a BBQ at the beach</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="food_array">
    <item>Make your family some cupcakes!</item>
    <item>Make your friend or family member some scrambled egg for breakfast!</item>
</string-array>
```

They are in a Listview where each row contains a checkbox and textview. MyActivity3:

```
public class MyActivity3 extends Activity {
private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);



    String[] listArray = new String[] { "All", "Friends", "Family", "Sports", "Outside","Money", "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach",  };
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("status", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Boolean[] checkedStatus = new Boolean[listArray.length];
    for ( int index = 0; index < checkedStatus.length; index++)
        checkedStatus[index] = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Integer.toString(index), false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, listArray, checkedStatus);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

}
```

In another activity, MyActivity2 there is a textview, where values get loaded from allthings_array:

```
<string-array name="allthings_array">
    <item>Make your friend or family member some scrambled egg for breakfast!</item>
    <item>Juggle a soccer ball for at least 100 times</item>
    <item>Head over to the movie house</item>
    <item>Take a selfie with a stranger!</item>
    <item>Play hide and seek with your friends!</item>
    <item>Do 10 push-ups without stopping</item>
    <item>Go outside and pick some flowers for your best friend!</item>
    <item>Help your neighbour with his homework!</item>
    <item>Make your family some cupcakes!</item>
    <item>Give it your best, take the best picture in history!</item>
    <item>Do 15 dips without stopping</item>
    <item>During your lunch break, go talk to one of your teachers! They might have something interesting to share with you</item>
    <item>Gather with your best friends and have a BBQ at the beach</item>
</string-array>
```

MyActivity2:

```
public class MyActivity2 extends Activity {
private String[] colors;
private String[] values;
private TextView tv;
private RelativeLayout rl;
Button n;
int index = 0;
int position2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_view);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);
    values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.allthings_array);
    colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorcode_array);

            n.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            if (index == 13) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "More coming each Sunday!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                position2 = (index++);
                            }
                            String textValue = values[position2];
                            tv.setText(textValue);
                            Random RAND = new Random();
                            int position = RAND.nextInt(colors.length);
                            String nextValue = colors[position];
                            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
                            n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00, 00, 00, 00));
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00, 00, 00, 00));
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Now what I need is that based on which checkboxes the user checks, the textView must load the appropiate values from the string_array's. So if for example I check "Beach" and "Money" in MyActivity3, then the textview in MyActivity2 must only load the values from beach_array and money_array.

How can I do this? I'd apreciate it if the examples are based on my code

EDIT:

MyActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private String[] colors;
private RelativeLayout rl2;
private MediaPlayer player;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonabout);
    rl2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_view2);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    v.setTypeface(typeface);
    m.setTypeface(typeface);
    colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorcodebored_array);
    Random RAND = new Random();
    int position = RAND.nextInt(colors.length);
    String nextValue = colors[position];
    rl2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pleasant);
    player.start();
}

public void openNewActivity(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
}

public void openNewActivity2(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);//Best if you use some static int
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation5, R.anim.animation6);
}

public void openNewActivity3(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
    }
}
```

Comment: MyActivity3 will open MyActivity2 when the users taps a button or something right? If that is the case you can just set the values on your intent, I can give you some sample code...just need to make sure I'm aiming for the right problem

Comment: Well not exactly, when you open the app you get to the homescreen which contains a few buttons. One of the buttons opens MyActivity3 and one of the buttons opens MyActivity2. MyActivity3 has the listview and MyActivity2 has the textView

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since both Activities are called from your "Homescreen" you just need to work with the method "onActivityResult" and also pass information inside your intent when calling your activity.

When calling your activity that holds your checkbox list you will start your activity expecting a result (the checked values):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyCheckboxActiity.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);//Best if you use some static int
```

When you are done with your checkbox activity you will put all your values inside your intent and publish them as a result for the homescreen activity:

```
 Intent myIntent = getIntent();
 myIntent.putExtra(MY_VALUE, myValue);
 setResult(MY_ACTIVITY_RESULT, myIntent);
 finish();
```

This will call your method onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //Store your data or do what you want
}
```

Since you know have your data stored inside your activity you can call your other activity passing the information through intent :)

Comment: Sorry to be such a pain. I kinda get what you are saying but I am not capable yet of adding it to my code.. Could you edit it into my code? again, sorry. :)

Comment: I don't like to give the answer.I think we can try to help you understand what you need to do :) Where are you lost about this?

Comment: Basically all over. The thing is I kind of understand what you mean, but where to place it in my code? No idea... For example, the first lines of code you gave, do I add them to MyActivity3? In the onCreate method?

Comment: The first code is to call your checkbox activity, so this will be placed where you call your checkbox activity now, in your homescreen activity (probably inside onClick method of your button)

Comment: I added MyActivity to the original post. Could you check if I did it right?

Comment: Okay, then the next few lines of code go to MyActivity3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59762/discussion-between-cristianowilson-and-ghostderfel).